# How to create checkbox in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I need a checkbox control in xamarin forms, and also the event when the control is check, how can I get this, I am using switch control, But its not having any event when IsChecked as changed, I need to group the checkbox, its not possible in switch control in xamarin forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Checkbox in Xamarin.Forms in Xaml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772510/how-to-add-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms-in-xaml-file)

Comment: If you are looking for a way to create your own checkbox I answered that here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772510/how-to-add-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms-in-xaml-file/39687160#39687160

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Switch control has a [Toggled](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=E%3AXamarin.Forms.Switch.Toggled) event that will fire when the state is changed.

Forms does not have a Checkbox control because there is no underlying Checkbox control in each mobile platform for it to map to.

[XF Labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) (an open source set of extensions for XF) does have a beta checkbox control that may fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomCheckbox : Image
{
        private const string CheckboxUnCheckedImage = "checkbox_unchecked";
        private const string CheckboxCheckedImage = "checkbox_checked";

    public CustomCheckbox()
    {
        Source = CheckboxUnCheckedImage;
        var imageTapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        imageTapGesture.Tapped += ImageTapGestureOnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(imageTapGesture);
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ImageTapGestureOnTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            Checked = !Checked;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The checked changed event.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<bool> CheckedChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// The checked state property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty CheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Checked", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomCheckbox), false, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnCheckedPropertyChanged);

    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            if (Checked != value)
            {
                SetValue(CheckedProperty, value);
                CheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e?.PropertyName == IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            Opacity = IsEnabled ? 1 : 0.5;
        }
    }

    private static void OnCheckedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var checkBox = bindable as CustomCheckbox;
        if (checkBox != null)
        {
            var value = newValue as bool?;
            checkBox.Checked = value.GetValueOrDefault();
            checkBox.Source = value.GetValueOrDefault() ? CheckboxCheckedImage : CheckboxUnCheckedImage;
        }
    }
}
```