# CheckBox throwing exception in xamarin forms even after adding Xamarin.Forms.Labs Package

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I am trying to add Checkbox in Xamarin.Forms PCL project in **Xamarin Studio Starter Edition**.I refered this link [How to create checkbox in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477132/how-to-create-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms)  to add Checkbox.Then Successfully added Xamarin.Forms.Labs Package Through Nuget Package Manager.I added namespace

xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"

in my xaml page. After Running the project i got  Could not load file or assembly 'XLabs.Forms' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified throws exception. Please anyone tell me the problem.

Comment: You should add XLabs.Forms from NuGet instead of Xamarin.Forms.Labs.

Comment: @SKall i added XLabs.Forms package.Then i got result in android.but when i run the iOS it throws following exception: "Could not load file or assembly 'XLabs.Forms' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." Can you figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Have you migrated the application to Xamarin.iOS from MonoTouch?

Comment: @SKall I am very new to Xamarin. In Appdelegate.cs file Monotouch prefix not there. so i think migrated. **System.AppDomain.Load (assemblyRef={XLabs.Forms}, assemblySecurity=(null)) in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:745** call stack shows this message. If you dont have any problem can you mesage your skype id to mahabaleshwarhnr@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it was because I hadn't followed the instructions on this page https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki

You need to make sure you change your AppDelegate to derive from XFormsApplicationDelegate, this fixed the rpoblem for me.

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : XFormsApplicationDelegate
```

Comment: You also have to install XLabs.Forms in the iOS Packages folder in order to recognise the XFormsApplicationDelegate.