# How to add Checkbox in Xamarin.Forms in Xaml file?

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, xamarin.ios

I'm completely new to xamarin.forms, I need to add a checkbox, radio buttons and drop down list. I tried some samples from net but I'm not able to get the checkbox. Can anyone help me to achieve this in xamarin.forms?

Xaml file

```
<toolkit:CheckBox Text ="Employee"
                  FontSize="20"
                  CheckedChanged ="OnClicked"/>
```

or

```
<controls:CheckBox DefaultText="Default text"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               TextColor="Green"
                               FontSize="25"
                               FontName="AmericanTypewriter"/>
```

Some links or sample code will make it easier to understand.

Comment: I found this sample to be very helpful: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CheckBox-Sample-in-b3ff8b94

Answer (score 19):

I found a better way to do this which is to create your own. It was really quite simple. Create a cs file in a Resources project (or where ever you want) called CheckBox and paste this code:

```
namespace Resources.Controls
{

public class Checkbox : Button 
{
    public Checkbox()
    {
        base.Image = "Image_Unchecked.png";
        base.Clicked += new EventHandler(OnClicked);
        base.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(OnSizeChanged);
        base.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        base.BorderWidth = 0;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (base.Height > 0)
        //{
        //    base.WidthRequest = base.Height;
        //}
    }

    public static BindableProperty CheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Checked",
        returnType: typeof(Boolean?),
        declaringType: typeof(Checkbox),
        defaultValue: null,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: CheckedValueChanged);

    public Boolean? Checked
    {
        get
        {
            if (GetValue(CheckedProperty) == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return (Boolean)GetValue(CheckedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CheckedProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
            RaiseCheckedChanged();
        }
    }

    private static void CheckedValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != null && (Boolean)newValue == true)
        {
            ((Checkbox)bindable).Image = "Image_Checked.png";
        }
        else
        {
            ((Checkbox)bindable).Image = "Image_Unchecked.png";
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;
    private void RaiseCheckedChanged()
    {
        if (CheckedChanged != null)
            CheckedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private Boolean _IsEnabled = true;
    public Boolean IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            if (value == true)
            {
                this.Opacity = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Opacity = .5;
            }
            base.IsEnabled = value;
        }
    }

    public void OnEnabled_Changed()
    {

    }

    public void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Checked = !Checked;

        // Call the base class event invocation method.
        //base.Clicked(sender, e);
    }

}
}
```

There is probably a better way to do this but I just added the two images to the appropriate locations in each project (base for UWP, Resources/Drawable for Android).

[image]

Then to use it in your Xaml just do something like this (I used a converter bc I was binding to a string value):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Resources.Controls;assembly=Resources"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.CheckBoxExamplePage"
             Title=" Hygiene">
  <Grid Padding="1">
    <ScrollView Padding="4">
      <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
          <controls:Checkbox x:Name="cbHello" Text="Hello CheckBox" Checked="{Binding Path=My.Binding.Path, Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolean}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="16,0,0,0">
          <controls:Checkbox x:Name="cbDisabled" Text="Disabled Example" IsEnabled="False" Checked="{Binding Path=My.Binding.PathTwo, Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolean}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Note: You must set the BindingContext in your pages cs file for the check to work. So your Pages code behind file should look like this:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class CheckBoxExamplePage
    {
        public CheckBoxExamplePage(object MyBindingObject)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = MyBindingObject;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result!

[image]

Hope this helps someone!!

**UPDATE:**

The following is new code that removes the gray background on disabled and also allows text to wrap if it does not fit on the screen. This uses a ContentView that contains a grid that can expand based on the content.

```
    public class Checkbox : ContentView
{
    protected Grid ContentGrid;
    protected ContentView ContentContainer;
    public Label TextContainer;
    protected Image ImageContainer;

    public Checkbox()
    {
        var TapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        TapGesture.Tapped += TapGestureOnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(TapGesture);

        ContentGrid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(42) });
        ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        ContentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

        ImageContainer = new Image
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        };
        ImageContainer.HeightRequest = 42;
        ImageContainer.WidthRequest = 42;

        ContentGrid.Children.Add(ImageContainer);

        ContentContainer = new ContentView
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(ContentContainer, 1);

        TextContainer = new Label
        {
            TextColor = Color.White,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        ContentContainer.Content = TextContainer;

        ContentGrid.Children.Add(ContentContainer);

        base.Content = ContentGrid;

        this.Image.Source = "Image_Unchecked.png";
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    public static BindableProperty CheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Checked",
        returnType: typeof(Boolean?),
        declaringType: typeof(Checkbox),
        defaultValue: null,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: CheckedValueChanged);

    public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Text",
        returnType: typeof(String),
        declaringType: typeof(Checkbox),
        defaultValue: null,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: TextValueChanged);

    public Boolean? Checked
    {
        get
        {
            if (GetValue(CheckedProperty) == null)
                return null;
            return (Boolean)GetValue(CheckedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CheckedProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
            RaiseCheckedChanged();
        }
    }

    private static void CheckedValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != null && (Boolean)newValue == true)
            ((Checkbox)bindable).Image.Source = "Image_Checked.png";
        else
            ((Checkbox)bindable).Image.Source = "Image_Unchecked.png";
    }

    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;
    private void RaiseCheckedChanged()
    {
        if (CheckedChanged != null)
            CheckedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private Boolean _IsEnabled = true;
    public Boolean IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _IsEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _IsEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            this.Opacity = value ? 1 : .5;
            base.IsEnabled = value;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler Clicked;
    private void TapGestureOnTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            Checked = !Checked;
            if (Clicked != null)
                Clicked(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private static void TextValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((Checkbox)bindable).TextContainer.Text = (String)newValue;
    }

    public event EventHandler TextChanged;
    private void RaiseTextChanged()
    {
        if (TextChanged != null)
            TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get { return ImageContainer; }
        set { ImageContainer = value; }
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
            RaiseTextChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Kasper, Thanks for the great stuff. 
I tried your updated code but still i am getting an outlined border to my check boxes.Please let me know how i can remove that border. Also in my case i don't need any text against checkbox.

Comment: Hello Ravindra. I updated the code again to remove the border when hovering. The border was from the button that I was using. I removed the button and used a gesture recognizer. However if all you need is a checked or unchecked square then my example is overkill. Your example would be far more efficient. =)

Comment: See my answer from October 2019, starting with Xamarin 4.1 the checkbox is built-in: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58838628](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58838628)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Nuget package called Xlabs.form. Try to import it in your Xaml.cs file like:

```
using XLabs.Forms.Controls;
```

In addition, you also have to add the following line in your .cs file:

```
CheckBox chk=new CheckBox()
            {
                checked=false;
            };
```

In Xaml it is different:

```
<CheckBox  x:Name="checked" isSelected="{Binding flag}"/>
```

Or you can use `<controls:checkbox>`.

Note: Don't forget to add the below line in the Contentpage of Xaml:

```
 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
```

Comment: XLabs Forms has notified on their Github page that code is not being maintained. It may or may not support updated version of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Thank you for the information..Many of our projects are using Xlabs for checkbox.If any other plu-in support from Nuget Package we need to look for it..

Comment: With the help of above ans by @Sawan and using accepted ans from Xamarin forum I manged to create my own custom check box. You can link [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70704/checkbox-with-xamarin).

Comment: I can provide you class and implementation if required.SO ready to help.

Comment: Adding this Nuget package to my solution leads to 162 warnings due to incompatibility issues. It's very strange that Xamarin doesn't provide an out-of-the box solution for such a simple thing as a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the checkbox and dropdown in the .cs file of xamarin cross platform.I suggest you use cs files for creating the UI.Xamarin is providing the leverage to use any one of the feature either cs file or AXML file to create the UI

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XLabs.Forms.Controls;

namespace Facedetection
{
    public class firstPage : ContentPage
    {
        string statename;

        public firstPage ()
        {

            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox () {
                TextColor=Color.Blue,
                CheckedText="I am checked"

            };

            Picker statepick = new Picker ();
            statepick.WidthRequest = 300;
            statepick.Title = "Select a state";
            statepick.Items.Add ("India");
            statepick.Items.Add ("US");
            statepick.Items.Add ("Arizona");
            statepick.Items.Add ("China");

            statepick.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => {
                if (statepick.SelectedIndex == -1) {
                    DisplayAlert ("Title", "Item not selected", "ok");
                } else {
                    statename = statepick.Items [statepick.SelectedIndex];
                    Console.WriteLine ("Selected country is:" + statename);
                }
            };




            Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {
                    checkbox,statepick
                }
            };
        }
    }
}




worked for me
```

Comment: This does not answer the question which was how to add it in a Xaml file. Ty though for the contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kasper Answers, but using the image instead of a button so that it will not show the shadow.

```
public class CustomCheckbox : Image
{
    private const string CheckboxUnCheckedImage = "checkbox_unchecked";
    private const string CheckboxCheckedImage = "checkbox_checked";

    public CustomCheckbox()
    {
        Source = CheckboxUnCheckedImage;
        var imageTapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        imageTapGesture.Tapped += ImageTapGestureOnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(imageTapGesture);
        PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void ImageTapGestureOnTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            Checked = !Checked;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The checked changed event.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<bool> CheckedChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// The checked state property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty CheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Checked", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomCheckbox), false, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnCheckedPropertyChanged);

    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            if (Checked != value)
            {
                SetValue(CheckedProperty, value);
                CheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e?.PropertyName == IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            Opacity = IsEnabled ? 1 : 0.5;
        }
    }

    private static void OnCheckedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var checkBox = bindable as CustomCheckbox;
        if (checkBox != null)
        {
            var value = newValue as bool?;
            checkBox.Checked = value.GetValueOrDefault();
            checkBox.Source = value.GetValueOrDefault() ? CheckboxCheckedImage : CheckboxUnCheckedImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not allow for a datacontext or to set the text to a binding. I updated my original code to remove the gray background and also to allow for text wrapping if the checkbox text does not fit on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0 (shipped Summer 2019) there is a Checkbox built-in! Preferrably we use this in the future.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/checkbox-xamarin-forms-4-1-0-pre-release/

Just an example:

`<CheckBox IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0"/>`

Comment: The built in one doesnt allow material label

Answer (score 0):

Now Xamarin Forms has their own CheckBox.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```