# Checkboxes not visible in release mode UWP (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, xlabs

I'm completely new to xamarin.forms.

I used XLabs library to add checkboxes in my PCL project (Xamarin Forms).

When I run my app UWP ARM in Debug mode there's no error, but when I run the app in Release mode the checkboxes ARE never shown.

Is there any setting that I need to configure?

Comment: It seems that this library has some problems, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772510/how-to-add-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms-in-xaml-file) in order to get other approach.

Comment: I try these solutions but they don't help me.

Comment: XLabs are deprecated.  Don't use it.  For checkbox, why don't you use the Switch control?

Comment: Because I need to add a list of answers for a type of question and the Switch control isn't a solution for this of project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @hugo said that the XLabs library is no longer maintained. It may not work with newer versions of Xamarin.Forms. For your requirement, you could use `Switch` control to replacing checkbox or use custom checkbox control. The following code implemented a simple checkbox. For more please refer to [**Introduction to Custom Renderers**](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction/).

**CustomCheckBox.cs**

```
public class CustomCheckBox : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CheckedProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create("Checked", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomCheckBox), default(bool));

    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckedProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

**CustomCheckBoxRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomCheckBox), typeof(CustomCheckBoxRenderer))]
namespace LabsTest.UWP
{
    public class CustomCheckBoxRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomCheckBox, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CheckBox>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomCheckBox> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CheckBox());
            }
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.IsChecked = Element.Checked;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.Checked))
            {
                UpdateStatus();
            }
        }
        private void UpdateStatus()
        {
            Control.IsChecked = Element.Checked;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <local:CustomCheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" Checked="True">
    </local:CustomCheckBox>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Finally I added a custom renderer. Thank you!

Comment: I am using this implementation but when user checks the checkbox OnElementPropertyChanged never triggers for property Checked, but only for IsFocused .

Comment: I finally solved adding events subscription `Control.Checked += (s,r)=> { Element.Checked = true; };` and `Control.Unchecked += (s, r) => { Element.Checked = false; };` in the method `OnElementChanged`.