# How to implement checkbox in xamarin Forms, Can we design a checkbox using xaml in xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Xamarin forms , in UWP trying to Design a grid in which one of the columns need to have checkboxes. In order to delete and undelete a user by checking and unchecking the checkbox.

But my actual concern is: To know if we can design a checkbox using xaml in xamarin forms.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Checkbox in Xamarin.Forms in Xaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772510/how-to-add-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms-in-xaml-file)

Comment: this is duplicate question, check the flowing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772510/how-to-add-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms-in-xaml-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing a Grid using a column of multiple checkboxes is possible as you can see in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/checkbox for UWP XAML. In Xamarin  XAML you can use this [use this this control from GitHub](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/2.2.0/samples/XLabs.Samples/XLabs.Samples/Pages/Controls/CheckBoxPage.xaml).

Comment: This references the UWP checkbox control, not a Xamarin Forms checkbox

Comment: @Steve Chadbourne my bad. I edited to include a Xamarin XAML Forms reference in case that checkboxes is preferred to the Switch UI control.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices in implementing a checkbox in Xamarin Forms.

The easiest is to use the Switch control as [shown here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch/).

If this is not suitable, you will have to implement custom renders for each platform. There are a number of plugins available that you can use such as [this one](https://github.com/messier16/Forms.Checkbox), but each has its flaws. Have a look at the code on GitHub to see how each was implemented. I ended up implementing my own custom renderer, taking the best bits from each one.

Answer (score 0):

Updated 2021: Use the new inbuilt CheckBox

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/checkbox